# Emerging hot spot analysis on ArcGIS not analyzing the zeros

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-statistics, spatio-temporal-data

I'm trying to make 3D space-time cubes using ArcGIS Pro. When I enter my parameters to create the cubes, I choose the option of "fill empty bins with: zeros".

The information for this operation indicates a total of 2000 cubes and ArcGIS specifies that only 900 of them contain at least one data.

When I try to analyze the Emerging hot spot, it seems ArcGIS only calculates hot and cold spots on the 900 cubes containing data. Yet I specified to fill the empty cubes with zeros. When I did Getis-Ord G*, the results showed cold spots, yet with the Emerging hot spot analysis, no cold spots are detected. Do you know how to account for zeros?